# jQuery .hover change the css of an element that is not child

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I have been trying to make an element(A)'s display to block, when another element(B) has the mouse over it, and then return it to none after the mouse leaves A, here are my attempts so far:

First here's a part of the HTML

```
..
<ul>
<li class="firstli">
       <img class="userLogo" src="media/images/eSahara.jpg"><a href="">Configurer</a></li>
       <li><a href="" class="clear">Supprimer</a></li>
       <li><a href="logout">Déconnecter</a></li>
</ul>
      </li>                    
          </ul>
<div id="cimsgContainer"><p>Changer votre <br> image de profile</p></div>
```

and now my attempts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".userLogo").mouseenter(function(){$("#cimsgContainer").css("display","block");});
$(".userLogo").mouseleave(function(){$("#cimsgContainer").css("display","none");});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".userLogo").hover(function(){$("#cimsgContainer").css("display","block");},function(){$(this).css("display","none");});
    </script>
```

**Very important note:** I already did my research and all I found is to change a child's CSS when the parent is hovered, in my case B is not a child of A neither is A a child of B.
A's id = #cimsgContainer; B's id = #userLogo
Thank you

Comment: You are targeting an ID that doesn't exist. I see a class of userLogo, but not and ID.

Comment: Yes, I've changed it but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
<li class="firstli">
       <img class="userLogo" src="media/images/eSahara.jpg"><a href="">Configurer</a></li>
       <li><a href="" class="clear">Supprimer</a></li>
       <li><a href="logout">Déconnecter</a></li>
</ul>
      </li>                    
          </ul>
<div id="cimsgContainer"><p>Changer votre <br> image de profile</p></div>
<script>
$(".userLogo").hover(function(){ $("#cimsgContainer").css("display", "block"); }, function(){ $("#cimsgContainer").css("display", "none");});
</script>
```

Appears to work for me.

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

`#target` will select the element with the `id=target`.

`.target` will select all elements with `class=target`.

You need to properly target your image using the class selector. `$(".userLogo")`

Moreover, perhaps you wanted the element after the logo to show when hovered, but not show otherwise? In that case, you can try something like this:

```
$(".userLogo").hover(
  function(){$(this).next().show()},
  function(){$(this).next().hide()}
);
```

Here is a ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/3gPHR/)*** for that scenario

or more simply: 
`$(".userLogo").hover(function({$(this).next().toggle()});`(http://jsfiddle.net/3gPHR/2/)